# How to refresh only output panel when input file is using in visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce

How to refresh only output panel when apex:inputfile is using in visualforce page?i am using input file in a form and in the form i am using command button to rerender the output panel.but its showing error.can any body help me on this....

Comment: Could you include the code example? Very difficult to answer without seeing what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

To refresh only output panel when apex:inputfile is using in visualforce page done by using apex:actionRegion tag. I hope that, it's works perfectly. One of the sample code as follows for your reference

```
<apex:form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="frmId">

            <apex:pageMessages />
            <apex:pageBlock title="Upload a File" mode="edit">
                <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
                    <apex:actionRegion >
                        <apex:commandButton action="{!upload}" value="Save"/>
                    </apex:actionRegion>
                </apex:pageBlockButtons>

                <apex:pageBlockSection showHeader="false" columns="1" id="block1">
                <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" id="block13">
                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                        <apex:outputLabel value="Type"/>
                        <apex:actionRegion >
                            <apex:selectList size="1" multiselect="false" value="{!banner.Type__c}">
                                <apex:selectOptions value="{!TypeLists}"/>
                                <apex:actionSupport reRender="frmId" event="onchange" status="LoadingStatus"/>
                            </apex:selectList>
                        </apex:actionRegion>
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                        <apex:outputPanel id="pannelImgeId">
                            <apex:outputLabel value="File" id="imageblockId" rendered="{!banner.Type__c != 'Gallery'}"/>
                            <apex:inputFile value="{!image.body}" filename="{!image.name}" rendered="{!banner.Type__c != 'Gallery'}"/>
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:outputPanel id="block11">
                    <apex:pageBlockSection showHeader="false" columns="2"  rendered="{!banner.Type__c == 'Banner'}">
                        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                            <apex:outputLabel value="States"/>
                            <apex:selectList size="1" multiselect="false" value="{!stateNameValu}" id="stateNameId">
                                <apex:selectOptions value="{!StatesName}"/>
                            </apex:selectList>
                        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                        <apex:outputPanel >
                            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                                <apex:outputLabel value="Community VF Page" style="margin-right: 5%;"/>
                                <apex:selectList size="1" multiselect="false" value="{!banner.Community_VF_Page_Name__c}">
                                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!VFLists}"/>
                                </apex:selectList>
                            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                    </apex:pageBlockSection>
                    <apex:pageBlockSection showHeader="false" columns="2"  rendered="{!banner.Type__c == 'State Leader Board'}">
                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                        <apex:outputLabel value="States"/>
                        <apex:selectList size="1" multiselect="false" value="{!stateNameValu}" id="stateLeaderId">
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!StatesName}"/>
                        </apex:selectList>
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>

                <apex:pageBlockSection showHeader="false" columns="2" id="block12" rendered="{!banner.Type__c == 'Gallery'}">
                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                        <apex:outputLabel value="Select Gallery Name"/>
                        <apex:actionRegion >
                            <apex:selectList size="1" multiselect="false" value="{!galleryNameSelect}" id="SelectId">
                                <apex:selectOptions value="{!OldNames}"/>
                                <script> var SelectId = '{!$Component.SelectId}';</script>
                                <apex:actionSupport reRender="frmId" event="onchange" action="{!oldImages}" status="LoadingStatus"/>
                            </apex:selectList>
                        </apex:actionRegion>
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:outputPanel id="panelId">
                        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem rendered="{!galleryNameSelect == 'Custom'}" >
                            <apex:outputLabel value="Gallery Name" style="margin-right: 5%;"/>
                            <apex:inputText value="{!galleryName}" id="displayBlockId">
                                <script> var displayBlockId = '{!$Component.displayBlockId}';</script>
                            </apex:inputText>
                        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>                        
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                    <apex:actionFunction name="bulkAttach" action="{!uploadAttachmentController}" reRender="customIdImg" oncomplete="checkForUploadsId('{!parentId}');" status="LoadingStatus">
                    </apex:actionFunction>
                    <br/><br/>                    



                </apex:pageBlockSection>
                </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:pageBlock>

            <apex:pageBlock rendered="{!banner.Type__c == 'Gallery'}" title="Add Files"><br/>
                <apex:pageBlockSection id="attachId">
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="uploadTable">
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="file" multiple="true" id="filesInput" name="file"  style="width: 495px;"/></td>
                            <td class="buttonTD">
                                <input id="uploadButton" type="button" title="Upload" class="btn" value=" Upload " onclick="prepareFileUploads()"/>
                                <input id="clear" type="button" title="Clear" class="btn" value=" Clear " onclick="clearFiles()"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </apex:pageBlockSection><br/>
                <table class="UploadedFileTableCls" width="100%" style = "text-align:left; border: 1px solid #dededd; clear:both;display: none;">
                <!--<table class="UploadedFileTableCls" id="tableId" style="display: none;">-->
                    <thead>
                        <th width="1000px;">File Name</th>
                        <th width="1000px;">Action</th>
                    </thead>
                </table><br/>

                <div class="UploadedFileTableCls">
                    <div class="uploadBox">
                    </div>
                </div>   
            </apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:outputPanel id="oldImgId">
                <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!imageList.size !=0 }">
                    <apex:pageBlock rendered="{!banner.Type__c == 'Gallery'}"  title="Existing Files">
                        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!imageList}" var="imgVal">
                            <apex:column headerValue="File Name" value="{!imgVal.Name}" style="width: 30%;"/>
                            <apex:column headerValue="Images" style="width: 20%;">
                                <img src="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!imgVal.Id}" style="width:125px;height:120px;"/>
                            </apex:column>
                            <apex:column headerValue="Action">
                                <a href="#" onclick="deleteAttachmentOld('{!imgVal.Id}')">Remove</a>
                                <!--<apex:commandLink hreflang="#" value="Remove" reRender="none" onclick="deleteAttachmentOld('{!imgVal.Id}')"/>-->
                            </apex:column>
                        </apex:pageBlockTable>
                    </apex:pageBlock>
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:outputPanel>

            <apex:actionStatus id="LoadingStatus" onstart="$('.modall').show();" onstop="$('.modall').hide();"/>
            <apex:actionFunction status="LoadingStatus" name="deleteAttachments" action="{!deleteAttachRec}" reRender="attachId">
                <apex:param name="idss" assignTo="{!idAttach}" value=""/>
            </apex:actionFunction>
            <apex:actionFunction status="LoadingStatus" name="deleteAttachmentOld" action="{!deleteAttachRec}" reRender="oldImgId">
                <apex:param name="idss" assignTo="{!idAttach}" value=""/>
            </apex:actionFunction>
        </apex:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you cannot 'reRender' any component with InputFile component in the same form. But you can refresh the page with apex action method.
Try putting the outputPanel and commandButton in same actionRegion but not sure if it will work.

Please post the code if this does not answer your query.